# Whitelisted for PHP in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm completely new to GAE. I'm aiming to build a webapp on Google Cloud SQL and GAE, using PHP to write to/from the database. I've got it working locally through the GoogleAppEngineLauncher localhost server, both succeeding at HelloWorld and reading from the Google Cloud SQL through PHP. When I upload to GAE, not even the HelloWorld will work.

One guess would be that PHP is not enabled on my GAE. I clicked the opt-in, and it said I've been whitelisted, but how can I verify it is turned on?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Is anything being logged in the AppEngine admin console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no whitelisting anymore, anybody can use the runtime.

Suggest you go to the admin console and look at the logs for your application to try and debug what might be going wrong.